# Rails ORDER BY working differently depending on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement sortable columns in some tables I am building in a rails app.

I have two differenct models. One is "Bets":

```
class Bet < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :benchmark, presence: true
  has_many :picks, dependent: :destroy
end
```

The other is "Picks" which belongs to two resources, users and bets(above).

```
class Pick < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :bet
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :bet_id, presence: true
end
```

Bets and Picks both have a "Benchmark" value which is a float.

When I go to rails console and call this command:

```
@bets = Bet.all.order("benchmark")
```

I get:

```
 Bet Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "bets".* FROM "bets" ORDER BY benchmark LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

which is what I want. If I print out all the @bets' benchmarks, they print in order.

However, when I do the same thing for picks, I get this:

```
@picks = Pick.all.order("benchmark")

Pick Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "picks".* FROM "picks" **ORDER BY "picks"."created_at" DESC**, benchmark LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

No matter what I do, it will only order the picks by the "picks"."created_at" DESC.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think i just realized its from:   default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }. If I remove this, what kind of repercussions could I expect in the program?

Comment: That depends on the size of your application and test coverage, but usually removing a `default_scope` is a large refactor because of many untested dependencies on the behavior. Check and see if the `reorder` method accomplishes what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is due to the `default_scope` you're setting for the `Pick` model. This will make all default queries use that scope. As you can see in your generated SQL it's first ordering by `created_at desc` and then any other order attributes you use.

Default scope has long been considered an anti pattern in rails because it causes issues like what you're seeing. There are two ways to fix this.

1) If you're unsure where this default scope is being utilized within your codebase you may want to leave it. To get around the default scope you use [unscoped](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class) to remove it from the current query you're making.

```
@picks = Pick.all.unscoped.order("benchmark")
```

2) If you're not currently using that default scope anywhere. Remove it from the class and replace it with a normal [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope)

```
class Pick < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :bet
  scope :order_newest -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :bet_id, presence: true
end

# Use like this
@picks = Pick.all.order_newest
```